# Which to replace - the water heater or the 3-way switched plug adapter or something else

Tags: water-heater

The situation: There is a 5 year old electrical tank-less water heater. The water heater is connected to a 3-way switched plug adapter, which is shared with another two electrical devices, before connecting to the main switch. The water heater switch off itself even though the switch (3-way switched plug adapter) is on. The water heater plug feel hot (not warm) on touch. This has happen on multiple occasions for the past 2 days. The water heater is used not more than 10 times per day (not more than 25 minutes each time).

Should I replace the water heater or the 3-way switched plug adapter or something else?

Comment: If the water heater is shutting itself down, it sounds like it has some sort of internal breaker\safety cut-off.  Have you checked to see if the breaker is functioning properly on the circuit it's plugged into?

Comment: @Comintern, the main circuit breaker is working fine as the water heater did not trip the main breaker.

Comment: Same thing happens with air compressors when you overload them - is the heater getting really heavy use?

Comment: @Comintern The water heater is used not more than 10 times per day.

Comment: Where are you on this planet, and what make/model is this water heater?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to figure out what "3-way switched plug adapter" meant until I Googled it and realized it's a UK idiom.  So you mean one of these?

[image]

### *No. Just No.*

Unplug that on-demand heater at once.  An on-demand heater takes *far too much* power to work with those adapters. It needs to be directly plugged into a listed receptacle.  Realistically, it should probably have its own circuit, and be hard-wired onto that circuit so no plug is involved at all.  (though UK does have nice beefy plugs).

I think you'll find the heat is not from the plug proper, but from the 3-way adapter getting rather much too hot.

Those 3-way adapters are intended for things like cell phone chargers or at worst, a television.  Big loads like a heater are *right out*.  If in doubt, look at the amps, watts or VA the device draws, if it takes more than about 2 amps or 500 watts/VA, it's too much for one of these.